# cpio extract not working

Tags: command-line, bash

I'm trying to extract a package called initrd.lz. I am running these commands:

```
mkdir tmp
cd tmp
lzma -dc -S .lz ../initrd.lz | cpio -imvd –no-absolute-filenames
```

However, there are no files afterwards. It didn't extract anything. It outputs saying the blocks, but I don't see the extracted files anywhere. Why?

Thank you.

Comment: Try `... | cpio -imvdo –no-absolute-filenames >foobar.cpio`